# How Can I refer to the Variable in PHP (pg_query)?

Tags: php, sql

I want to insert a WKT format polygon to the PostGIS. It works with the PostGIS SQL. Now I want to use PHP call this function but it fails. It should be something wrong with the reference to the variable. My code is as following:

```
<?php 
$data = A string format data;
$con="host=localhost dbname=database user=postgres password=great";
$dbcon= pg_connect($con);

$sql="INSERT INTO polygons(geometry) VALUES (ST_GeomFromText(('$data'))";
$result= pg_query($dbcon,$pgsql);
?>
```

There should be something wrong with the `$data`, it doesn't refer to my data. But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I'm kinda hoping you haven't posted your real password there.

Comment: BTW: For safety and correctness never use PHP string interpolation when building SQL queries. Use prepared statements or at least escape the string (and escape as late as possible).

Comment: Don't worry, is not real password

Comment: what does `pg_last_error($dbcon)` give you? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-last-error.php

Comment: @Spudley Why? His host is `localhost`. Who cares what his password is?

Answer (score 1):

What every PHP user have to understand, that it is not into pg_query variable being inserted but into *regular PHP string*.

And thus it is very simple to verify if it was inserted or not - by just echoing the string out:

```
echo $sql;
```

This way you can see if it was inserted or not.

- if it was - the problem somewhere else.
- if won't - you have to verify variable itself.

Comment: It is not inserted since it doesn't take the value from the variable data.

Comment: Nope. that rather means that there is no data in the variable.

Comment: But I tried echo $data, it shows all the value of that variable.

Comment: Well it just can't be. May be you are echoing it somewhere else. But if your `$sql` doesn't contain the data, then neither `$data` contains it.

Comment: Thanks "YCS". It is working. It is an syntax error. I thought I switch on the Chinese Character, so something wrong with the quotation mark.